# Several PHP versions on Mac

Tags: php, macos

I have several versions of PHP on my Mac.  Problem is, whenever I try to install new libraries, I'm not sure which version I'm installing them to.  I'm using the command line on Mac OSX, and I read somewhere that you can change which PHP version you're installing libs to, but I can't figure out how to do it.  How do I tell which PHP version I'm dealing with on command line, and install libraries/modules only to that version?

Comment: `php -v` will tell you, and `which php` will tell you where the binary is.

Comment: @MarcB It looks like `which php` is pointing to the wrong version.  How do I change this?

Comment: `which` just scans through `$PATH` until it finds a match. if what it returns is the wrong version, then you'll have to fiddle with the path until the correct version's directory comes earlier in $PATH, or remove the bad versions until you get back the one you want.

Comment: @MarcB so `which php` doesn't affect where the packages are being installed?  How do I install a package to the location of the right version of PHP?